# Custom jinja2 filter for iterator

Tags: python, jinja2, customization

How do I most efficiently write a custom filter for Jinja2 that applies to an iterable like the built-in 'sort' filter, for use in a for loop in the template?

For example:

```
{% for item in iterable|customsort(somearg) %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters for general documentation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same way you'd write any other filter. Here's an example that should get you started:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, Undefined

def custom_sort(iterable, somearg):
    if iterable is None or isinstance(iterable, Undefined):
        return iterable

    # Do custom sorting of iterable here

    return iterable

# ...

env = Environment()
env.filters['customsort'] = custom_sort
```

Don't worry about efficiency until it becomes a problem. The template engine is unlikely to be the bottle-neck in any case.

Comment: thanks this helped me with this filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406939/how-to-clean-up-this-jinja2-and-or-boolean-expression

Comment: @include: I don't think you can use filters as if they were built-in functions -- `foo|ss` should work, but not `ss(foo)`. Does that help?

Comment: @Cameron no :( I still get the same error "TemplateAssertionError("no filter named 'ss'",)" with http://pastebin.com/QPYczXgH. I think this is way of creating env is not getting glued to bottle template env.

Comment: @include: Ah OK, sorry. I'm afraid I don't know how to bind it properly, as I've never really used bottle.

Comment: @Cameron oh ok, 10x anyway :)