# How to escape or unscape this sequence?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, escaping, jinja2

Hi how should I escape to make the link render?

[image]

The way I write it now is with filter:
`{{article.text|striptags|urlize|nl2br|safe}}`

Can you recommend how to do it?

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179801/autolinebreaks-filter-in-jinja2

Thank you

Comment: well, don't escape it at all if you want HTML tags to be interpreted as HTML tags.

Comment: but there was no difference in output rendering switching between `{{article.text|striptags|urlize|nl2br}}`and the escaped?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python HTML sanitizer / scrubber / filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699468/python-html-sanitizer-scrubber-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I'd like to use `HTMLParser` for processing (overkill maybe?), sample code below for Python 2.7 (3.0 library is renamed `html.parser`)

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Found Start Tag", attrs

s = "noivos, convites de casamento <a href=\"http://www.olharcaricato.com.br\">
        http://www.olharcaricato.com.br</a> more entries here"

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(s)
```

Outputs: `Found Start Tag [('href', 'http://www.olharcaricato.com.br')]`

Note: Implement the code above as a filter, tweak the output to your needs. Example of filter is found at [Custom jinja2 filter for iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481205/custom-jinja2-filter-for-iterator)

Comment: Cool solution! Thank you and as you say it might be overkill when all I really need right now is replace `\n`with `<br>`