# Jinja2 for loop behaving similarly to with

Tags: jinja2

I'd like to iterate over a set of objects and find the maximum of one particular attribute, however jinja2 ignores any action within an iterator on a variable declared outside of the iterator.  For example:

```
{% set maximum = 1 %}
{% for datum in data %}
    {% if datum.frequency > 1 %}
        {% set maximum = datum.frequency %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{# maximum == 1 #}
```

`datum.frequency` is definitely greater than 1 for some `datum` in `data`.

**EDIT (solution)**

This is *similar* to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486393/jinja2-change-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-loop), but there's a bit more to it.  The following works and is very ugly.

```
{% set maximum = [1] %}
{% for datum in data %}
    {% if datum.freq > maximum[-1] %}
        {% if maximum.append( datum.freq ) %}{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% set maximum = maximum[-1] %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered writing a custom filter to return the highest value of a particular attribute within your collection?  I prefer to minimize the amount of logic I use in Jinja2 templates as part of maintaining a 'separation of concerns'.

Here is a link to a very good example of how one can be written in python:
[Custom jinja2 filter for iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481205/custom-jinja2-filter-for-iterator)

Once you have your filter returning the value you need access it by using '|' like so:

```
{% set maximum = datum|filtername %}
```