# python Jinja2 creating a file from json template using yaml conf

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, yaml, jinja2

I am writing a function to render json template using yaml config file.

It looks something like below :

`render.py`:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "usage: python render_template.py [yaml_file] [jinja_template_file]"
    sys.exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as stream:
    config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as stream:
    template_text = stream.read()
template = Template(template_text)

print template.render(config)
```

`test.yaml`:

```
    Application:
          Hosts:
              - a
              - b
```

sample.json.templete

```
     [{
"test1": 
{

                  "objectName": "{{Application.Hosts}}",

                 }


}]
```

when I run

```
   python ./render.py ./test.yaml ./sample.json.templete > sample.json
```

I get

```
   [{
"test1": 
{

                  "objectName": ['a' , 'b'],

                 }


}]
```

But since I am generating a json file I need

```
     ["a", "b"]
```

I.e. I want the list in double quotes. How do I best achieve it? How do I convert list with strings in single quotes to list with strings in double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom filter function in your template to format lists just the way you want them. You could then use this function for any list you want to format.

A good SO question/answer with some great info on creating a jinja2 filter to use with an iterable (e.g. your list) [is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481205/custom-jinja2-filter-for-iterator)

Then your json template can use the filter like this:

```
    "objectName": "{{ Application.Hosts|format_list }}",
```

Your filter would most likely do something like this:

```
def format_list(my_list):
    formatted_list = ", ".join(["%s" % item for item in my_list]) 
    return "[%s]" % formatted_list
```

Comment: where would I define this function? inside sample.json.templete file?

Comment: in your python file - you'd need to define it and add it to jinja's env before you call template.render. The answer I linked to has a full example of that side of things.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
["{{Application.Hosts|join('","')}}"]
```

We don't need to make any custom filters